# Python-requests response headers are empty when response contains double headers

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to login into this IoT device using python-requests. But I noticed that response headers are empty. Further investigation and I think I found the reason: double headers on response.

Response captured with wireshark:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
...
```

It seems that requests reads only the first "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" and nothing more as trying to run for example this:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://10.0.0.10/cgi-bin/index')
print(r.headers)
```

returns this:

```
{}
```

I need to receive "Set-cookie" header in order to manage the device. What should I do? Should I try to read raw http response and try to parse the "Set-cookie" header?

Comment: Are you certain the wireshark capture is accurate? What if you just use `curl` with the `--trace-ascii` option? If the wireshark trace is accurate, your device is clearly returning an invalid response and I wouldn't expect anything to parse it correctly.

Comment: Yes it is accurate. I see the same with chrome developer tools.